# html5 canvas - Update text

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Here's my project: http://jsfiddle.net/fknjz/17/

When I type in the textboxes under the canvas and click "UPDATE", it works and add the text in the canvas. But every time I click UPDATE, it adds the textbox content over the content typed before. So the text in the canvas starts stacking up on each other.

What I need is to modify the text in the Canvas so that when I click UPDATE, it actually updates the text, not create a new text line of text over the old one.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clear the canvas like so:

```
canvas.width = canvas.width;
```

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fknjz/22/). Note that you need to redraw the image each time since the canvas is completely cleared.

Or, as suggested by apsillers and Joceyln, use the `clearRect` method of canvas. This, however, will require you to calculate the area of the rectangle you want to clear which may need to vary depending on the amount of text the user enters and will remove sections of the image you have drawn in the background (which may not be an issue if it's always going to be a white background).

Comment: Where do I have to put this line? Thanks!

Comment: The answer works, but you should consider using ctx.clearRect()

Comment: Thanks Jocelyn, I've added your suggestion. However, for the particular requirements of the poster, I think clearing the whole canvas is a better approach (and probably easier to understand).

Comment: Ok, get it. And what about redrawing the background image? Do I have to create another function that will redraw the background image when I click UPDATE? Or something?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I'd done it in the original fiddle. I've edited the post with an updated fiddle. But yes, using a function to update the image is definitely better than the way I've implemented it (very quickly) because it avoids repetition of the code.

Answer (score 8):

Remember that the canvas is just a bunch of pixels: when you make that call to `fillText`, the canvas doesn't see characters, it sees a set of pixels.  Furthermore, that set of pixels, as a distinct group, is immediately lost -- there's no way to ask the canvas, "Please remove that specific set of pixels I just added."

Your options are:

- Using [clearRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CanvasRenderingContext2D#clearRect%28%29) to wipe away a rectangular section of your drawing.
- Using `canvas.width = canvas.width;` to reinitialize the pixel state of the canvas.  This requires you to redraw the entire canvas, whereas `clearRect` gives you more precision.

For future work, you might consider using a [canvas drawing library](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=js+canvas+library) that can maintain state about the components of your drawing and allow you to remove or alter specific elements.